# Saving Password in icloud keychain

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, icloud

I have built an app where to access the calendar and information you have to go through a login page. I know users like it when their email and password are saved and they do not have to fill it out but I don't know how to make iCloud keychain available to my app. Any help is very much appreciated.
EDIT

Would this link work at all. If it does how would I have to change it?
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Apple has an API for Apple Keychain, and includes a page of Developer docs as well, you should check it out. Let me know if you get stuck!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services?preferredLanguage=occ

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! I will try it out now!